# Wordpress wp_mail() not working when user not logged in?

Tags: wordpress

This is my code to send mail.

```
$htmlcontent = "Quick Contact";
$to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
$subject = "Quick Contact";
$headers = "Quick Contact";
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $htmlcontent );
```

This code works fine when the user is logged in. When the user is not logged in the mail is not sent.

Comment: It should. Where did you place this piece of code?

Comment: i write that code into the functions.php file.

Comment: post the complete code, means the function, it is part of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of try this code.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax', 'my_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax', 'my_ajax');
```

add ajax to register or non register user allow to access.